# Who is the Earth silhouette in the intro to Avatar: The Last Airbender?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

The intro to *Avatar: The Last Airbender* shows a silhouette of a character of each of the four elements. I believe:

- Water is Pakku (Katara's grandfather)
- Fire is Azula (Zuko's sister)
- Air is obviously Aang.

Who is the Earth character? Is it the teenager that got got in trouble with the Fire Nation for practicing the prohibited Earth bending that eventually joined Team Avatar for a short while (don't remember the name)?

[image]

Here is a YouTube link to the intro:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going directly from the [*Avatar* wiki entry on the Opening Sequence](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Opening_sequence), the silhouette is [**Sud**](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sud), [Avatar Roku's](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Roku) earthbending teacher.

> The sequence opens by showcasing the four elemental bending styles: waterbending, earthbending, firebending, and airbending. The waterbending is performed by Pakku, the earthbending by Sud, the firebending by Azula, and the airbending by an Air Nomad.

From Sud's wiki entry:

> Of the four shadowed benders featured in the opening sequence, Sud was the third, and currently last, to have been identified, after Pakku and Azula.

[image: Sud]

The reasoning for this is as follows:

> Sud's character design was confirmed by Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko to be a prototype for Toph Beifong.
>   <sub>[Toon Zone News Interviews Bryan Konietzko & Mike DiMartino](http://www.toonzone.net/toon-zone-news-interviews-bryan-konietzko-and-mike-dimartino-avatar/)</sub>

From [Toph's Wiki entry](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Toph_Beifong) under Original Design:

> This idea made its way into the opening sequence, as the shadowed earthbender was confirmed by the creators to be Toph's "prototype" and in the opening sequence of the unaired pilot episode."

And on [The Boulder's wiki entry](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Boulder), under Trivia:

> He bore a resemblance to Sud, Roku's earthbending teacher, who was modeled after an early design of Toph.

Comment: Additionally, the Airbender in the sequence isn't actually Aang. You can see that the nomad in question is much older and taller than Aang is throughout the series.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - Yet the Airbender has glowing Avatar eyes if you look closely. Are you saying it's some previous airbending Avatar? I believe it's clearly Aang. Who else would it be? It's just like the Waterbender in the *The Legend of Korra* intro is Korra.

Comment: @iMerchant I see no glowing "Avatar State" eyes. The reason Korra is used in her respective opening is because _The Legend of Korra_ uses Kyoshi, Roku and Aang for the other 3 elements. _The Legend of Aang_ uses Pakku, (ssemingly) Sud and Azula. They're not Avatars, and they're not directly related to the Avatar. Following that trend, the Airbender is an unidentified Air Nomad who was likely designed to be a character in the show, but later dropped when the writers finalised the "Sozin destroyed the Air Nation" story arc.

Answer (score -1):

That's [The Boulder](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/The_Boulder)

The Boulder was a professional earthbending wrestler who participated in the Earth Rumble tournaments. Toph beats him in five seconds flat. He later went on to fight for the Earth Kingdom and assist in the invasion of the Fire Nation along with The Big Bad Hippo.

Comment: Are u sure? I disagree. He's too bulky to be in that silhouette

Comment: The same haircut and beard, mostly. But he is slightly less bulky  when the Gaang meets him again before the attack on Fire Kingdom.

Comment: @iMerchant The Boulder isn't the fat guy, it's the guy who beats him. Nevertheless, the other answer is pretty conclusive.